# What's allowed in a Perl 6 identifier?

Tags: unicode, raku

[Synopsis 2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/perl6/specs/master/S02-bits.pod) says:

> An *identifier* is composed of an alphabetic character followed by any sequence of alphanumeric characters.  The definitions of alphabetic and numeric include appropriate Unicode characters.  Underscore is always considered alphabetic.  An identifier may also contain isolated apostrophes or hyphens provided the next character is alphabetic.

[Syntax](http://doc.perl6.org/language/syntax#Identifiers) in the Perl 6 docs says:

> Identifiers are a grammatical building block that occur in several places. An identifier is a primitive name, and must start with an alphabetic character (or an underscore), followed by zero or more word characters (alphabetic, underscore or number). You can also embed dashes - or single quotes ' in the middle, but not two in a row.

The term "appropriate Unicode character" begs the question that we know what appropriate is.

I find that to be too vague if I'm going to choose beyond ASCII characters. I find in Perl6::Grammar this production, but not the definition for `<.ident>`:

```
token identifier {
    <.ident> [ <.apostrophe> <.ident> ]*
}
```

But this also begs the question that you have to know what an identifier is to define an identifier. So, where is `<.ident>`?

raiph points out that `<.ident>` is the `ident` method in `QRegex::Cursor`, but that defines it in terms of `nqp::const::CCLASS_WORD`. Now I have to track down that.

---

I tried to use U+00B2 (SUPERSCRIPT TWO) (General categories No, Other_Number) because I wanted to pass around the result of an expensive square operation, and hey, Perl 6 is supposed to allow this:

```
my $a² = $a**2;
```

But, it turns out that ², along with the other superscripts, are operators. That's fine, but ² and the like aren't [listed as an operator](http://doc.perl6.org/language/operators) or in `Int` or the behavior `Int` inherits:

```
$ perl6 -e 'my $Δ² = 6; say $*PERL; say $Δ²'
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in numeric context  in block <unit> at -e line 1
Cannot modify an immutable Int
  in block <unit> at -e line 1

$ perl6 -e 'my $Δ = 6; say $*PERL; say $Δ²'
Perl 6 (6.c)
36

$ perl6 -e 'my $Δ = 6; say $*PERL; say $Δ³'
Perl 6 (6.c)
216

$ perl6 -e 'my $Δ = 6; say $*PERL; say $Δ⁹'
Perl 6 (6.c)
10077696
```

But I can't use ½ U+00BD (VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF) (General categories of No and Other_Number):

```
$ perl6 -e 'my $Δ½ = 6; say $*PERL; say $Δ½'
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling -e
Bogus postfix
at -e:1
------> my $Δ⏏½ = 6; say $*PERL; say $Δ½
    expecting any of:
        constraint
        infix
        infix stopper
        postfix
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
```

But, what if I don't put a number in `$Δ`?

```
$ perl6 -e 'my $Δ = "foo"; say $*PERL; say $Δ²'
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏foo' (indicated by ⏏)
```

in block  at -e line 1

```
Actually thrown at:
```

in block  at -e line 1

I was worried that someone defining a postfix operator could break the language, but this seems to work:

```
$ perl6 -e 'multi sub postfix:<Δ>(Int $n) { 137 }; say  6Δ;'
137

$ perl6 -e 'multi sub postfix:<Δ>(Int $n) { 137 }; my $ΔΔ = 6; say $ΔΔ;'
6

$ perl6 -e 'multi sub postfix:<Δ>(Int $n) { 137 }; my $Δ = 6; say $ΔΔ;'===SORRY!=== Error while compiling -e
Variable '$ΔΔ' is not declared
at -e:1
------> fix:<Δ>(Int $n) { 137 }; my $Δ = 6; say ⏏$ΔΔ;
```

So, what's going on there?

Comment: Superscripts are listed as operations in the identifier section online: [Identifiers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Identifiers).

Comment: Superscripts are listed now, but they weren't when I asked this question. A deleted answer references https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1098 as the issue that noted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The grammar has an identifer [defined as](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/386905f/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L449)

```
token apostrophe {
    <[ ' \- ]>
}

token identifier {
    <.ident> [ <.apostrophe> <.ident> ]*
}
```

with `ident` a [method on cursors](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/21e8038/src/QRegex/Cursor.nqp#L670) which accepts input that starts with a `CCLASS_ALPHABETIC` character or an underscore `_` and continues with zero or more `CCLASS_WORD` characters.

These classes are [implemented in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/45b7c8a/src/strings/ops.c#L1537) and map to various Unicode categories.

Specifically, `CCLASS_ALPHABETIC` checks for *Letter, Lowercase*; *Letter, Uppercase*; *Letter, Titlecase*; *Letter, Modifier* and *Letter, Other*.

`CCLASS_WORD` additionally accepts characters of category *Number, Decimal Digit* as well as undercores.

As to why postfix operators do not break identifiers, that's due to longest token matching.

If you want to call a postfix operator `Δ` on a variable `$Δ`, you have to add a backslash, ie

```
multi sub postfix:<Δ>(Int $n) { 137 };
my $Δ = 6;
say $Δ\Δ;
```

or an 'unspace'

```
say $Δ\   Δ;
```

Comment: The backslash is an unspace, just without any spaces to undo. You could also state that you can use the fully qualified name of the postfix operator `say postfix:<Δ> $Δ;`