# Define ⊤ ("down tack") character as a constant I can use in my program

Tags: constants, declaration, raku, initializer

I'm trying to write some logical statements in Perl6.

I've made logical operators:

```
multi sub prefix:<¬> ($n) {
    return not $n;
}

multi sub infix:<∧> ($n, $b) {
        return ($n and $b);
}

multi sub infix:<∨> ($n, $b) {
        return ($n or $b);
}

multi sub infix:<⇒> ($n, $b) {
        if $n == True and $b == True {
                return True;
        } elsif $n == True and $b == False {
                return False;
        } elsif $n == False {
                return True;
        }
}

multi sub infix:<⇐> ($n, $b) {
        return $b ⇒ $n;
}
```

But would like to be able to introduce new symbols for true and false. At the moment, I have:

```
say ((False ⇒ ¬(False ∨ True)) ∧ (False ∨ True));
```

But, I would like:

```
say ((⟂ ⇒ ¬(⟂ ∨ ⊤)) ∧ (⟂ ∨ ⊤));
```

I thought maybe I could make define these symbols as constants:

```
constant ⊤ = True;
constant ⊥ = False;
```

But, if I do that then I get this error:

> Missing initializer on constant declaration at
>   /home/devXYZ/projects/test.pl6:1

Comment: See also [What's allowed in a Perl 6 identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34689850/2173773)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `⊤` character is not valid as an identifier:

```
say "⊤" ~~ /<.ident>/; # Nil
```

Even if the `constant` syntax allowed declaration of such a name, there wouldn't be a way to use it, since symbol name parsing only looks for identifiers also.

What's needed is to introduce it as a new term. This is much like adding a prefix or infix operator, in that it extends the language to accept things it otherwise would not. That can be done using `constant`, like this:

```
constant \term:<⊤> = True;
say ⊤; # True
```

To be sure you are using the correct unicode character in the definition and usage lines you can use the convenient `.&uniname` method. Different characters can look similar with certain fonts:

```
> say "⟂".&uniname
PERPENDICULAR
> say "⊥".&uniname
UP TACK
```

Comment: the single quote `'` in the first piece of code doesn't belong there. I tried to edit it out, but stackoverflow doesn't allow edits shorter than 6 characters …

Comment: fixed it by being more verbose ;-)